# scala hibernate/jpa - ignore autogenerated bitmap$init$0 mapping

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa

Trying to use hibernate/jpa with scala. Running into interesting issue.

This is my entity definition.

```
@Entity
class Product(n: String, d: Double) extends EntityBase {

  def this() = this("", 0)
  def this(n: String) = this(n, 0)

  var name: String = n
  var price: Double = d

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="orderId")
  var order: Order = _

  override def toString = "Product: " + id + " " + name
}
```

When I run hibernate query I'm getting the following exception:

```
[SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column this_.bitmap$init$0 does not exist Position: 29]
```

Obviously jpa by default creates mapping for scala autogenerated field bitmap$init$0. I don't know what causing scala to generate it. But regardless is there any solution to tell jpa to ignore it? Or somehow remove it from hibernate mapping? Or maybe something else..

Comment: I have absolutely same trouble. But it looks like there are only two persons who meet it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where that autogenerated field is coming from, but you could try to streamline your class to have less fields:

```
@Entity
class Product(var name: String = "", var price: Double = 0) extends EntityBase {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="orderId")
  var order: Order = _

  override def toString = "Product: " + id + " " + name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple of interesting things about this issue.

I have this `Model` class in my application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
class User extends Model{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="users_id_seq")
  @Column(name="id", updatable=false, nullable=false)
  val id:Long = 0L

  @BeanProperty var name:String = _
  @BeanProperty var email:String = _
```

}

This class is compiled to a java class named `User`, which in turn is defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@ScalaSignature(bytes=long array of bytes)
public class User extends Model
   implements ScalaObject, EntityBean
{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="users_id_seq")
   @Column(name="id", updatable=false, nullable=false)
   private final long id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private volatile int bitmap$init$0;
   private static String _EBEAN_MARKER = "models.User";

   ...

   public long id()
  {
    if ((_ebean_get_bitmap$init$0() & 0x1) != 0)
    {
        _ebean_get_id(); return _ebean_get_id(); 
   } 
   throw new 
         UninitializedFieldError("Uninitialized field: User.scala: 17".toString());
    }

   public String name()
   {
   if ((_ebean_get_bitmap$init$0() & 0x2) != 0)
   {
     _ebean_get_name(); return _ebean_get_name();
   } throw new 
           UninitializedFieldError("Uninitialized field: User.scala: 19".toString()); 
   } 

   public void name_$eq(String paramString) { 
     _ebean_set_name(paramString); 
      _ebean_set_bitmap$init$0(_ebean_get_bitmap$init$0() | 0x2);
   }

  ....
```

The `bitmap$init$0` actually comes from a class enhancement, and I thought that the responsible was the `Ebean` library, which I'm currently using. But after reading your post I went to investigate if JPA itself was doing some sort of bytecode enhancement on this object.
In order to check this out, I created a copy project, but in Java. The generated code for the `User` class happens to have no `bitmap$init$0` field, as follow:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="users_id_seq")
  @Column(name="id", updatable=false, nullable=false)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String email;

 public void setId(Long id)
 {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public Long getId() {
   return this.id;
 }

public String getName() {
   return this.name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
 }
 public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
 }
 public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

All this kind of trouble led me to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bescala/kxMC1kQRD_U/eWbP7QG4yIoJ) and I most certainly agree. It seems that integrating JPA to Scala Ebean/Hibernate is kind of a real pain. I still didn't understand if this `bitmap$ini$0` field in injected to the class bytecode by Ebean or something else.

It seems that you can try to bypass this kind of behavior by associating an annotation (`@Transitent`) to the generated Java bytecode, by compiling the code first for java then to Scala, something similar to what is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493543/compiling-java-annotations-with-sbt). But I really don't think that's really worthy!