# Compiling Java annotations with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I've created Java annotations (since I need run time retention) under `$PROJECT/src/main/java` and my scala codewhich uses these java annotations us under `$PROJECT/src/main/scala`. The Java annotation thus created also makes use of a Java ENUM as it's value.

If I compile the project then sbt doesn't seem to compile the Java annotations first and errors out on each usage of the  enum in annotations. If I comment out all usages of the Java enum in annotations in scala code and do a compile, uncomment enum usage and compile again it all works fine.

How do I ensure that sbt compiles my java annotations and enum (i.e. `$PROJECT/src/main/java`) before attempting to compile scala code when doing a clean build?

EDIT: I have a bare bones build.sbt and am using sbt 0.11.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some good news: This is [a known issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2764) and has been resolved.

Some bad news: It's resolved in 2.10 and the fix may not be backported to 2.9.3 (quoting Paul Phillips in the issue thread):

> I've tagged this for backporting, which is not a guarantee; I don't
>   have time to do it right now but I expect to in the near future.

Some good news: If you're stuck on pre-2.10 and your Java sources don't depend on your Scala sources, [you can just add the following](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Java-Sources) to your `build.sbt` and all is well:

```
compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala
```

Some bad news: If you're stuck on pre-2.10 and your Java sources do depend on your Scala sources, I'm pretty sure you're out of luck, and the comment-compile-uncomment trick is probably your best bet.

Comment: Fortunately for now my Java sources are independent of the scala code and the above trick does allow it to compile fine. However, the publish-local command still seems to fail with same. Is there a way to fix it quickly?

Comment: @cracked_all: If you don't care about publishing the docs, you can add `publishArtifact in packageDoc := false` to your `build.sbt` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you're facing [SI-2764](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2764). This has been fixed in Scala 2.10.

In the meantime, create a separate sub-project for your Java annotations, and depend on this from the project containing the Scala code.. Then the Scala compiler will *only* process the .class files, rather the .java files.