# How to exclude ebeans from Play 2.0?

Tags: hibernate, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using Play 2.0 with Scala and JPA/Hibernate. Hibernate creates the DB structure automatically and inserts strange columns like `bitmap$init$0` what should be due to ebean (as far as I know).

I tried to disable ebean with the following setting in my ApplicationBuild object:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  ebeanEnabled := false
)
```

But the strange columns are generated anyway.

How can I disable ebean?

Comment: Do you still have Ebean enabled in your `conf/application.conf`? There might be a line like `ebean.default="models.*"`. If you comment it out, Ebean should be disabled.

Comment: The word "ebean" is not in my application.conf. Any other idea?

Comment: No, sorry. Are you sure this issure is caused by Ebean? (Not saying that it isn't, but of course it would be nice to rule out other possibilities.)

Comment: ebean was only my first guess after some google search.

Comment: This seems to be a general issue with JPA and Scala (it [also occurs with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760970/scala-hibernate-jpa-ignore-autogenerated-bitmapinit0-mapping) ). Please [have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13327497/1071311) to see where the problem is and for a bit of a workaround. (spoiler: Scala generates the `bitmap$init$0` when compiling to Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pretty simple solution is to [upgrade](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration) to Play 2.1. Thanks to modularization ebean is not longer included by default.