# Scala 2.9.1 issue? => MappingException: Setting property bitmap$init$0 to null

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I use scala 2.9.1, Play Framework 2.0.4, Spring 3.2.0, Spring Data 2.1.0 and neo4j 1.8.

I've got this model object:

```
package models

import java.lang.{String, Long}
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.{Indexed, NodeEntity, GraphId}

    @NodeEntity
    class Article(_title: String) {

      @GraphId var id: Long = _     //causes the error !!

      @Indexed val title: String = _title

      def this() {
        this("no title")
      }

      override def hashCode(): Int = {
        41 * title.hashCode
      }

      override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = {
        other match {
          case that: Article => (that canEqual this) && ((this.id == that.id) && (this.title == that.title))
          case _ => false
        }
      }

      def canEqual(other: Any) = other.isInstanceOf[Article]
    }
```

Before, I used Scala 2.10 with Play Framework 2.1-RC2 and the same version of Spring Data, nothing bad happened and I never touched the code since (it's a personal project).

I've got this error:

```
MappingException: Setting property `bitmap$init$0` to null on models.Article@466b9021
```

I found this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760970/scala-hibernate-jpa-ignore-autogenerated-bitmapinit0-mapping/13327497#13327497) explaining (especially in the comments) that it seems that anterior scala version to 2.10.0 causes the issue.

Has anyone come across this issue? How could I fix it?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I've deleted my answer to avoid misinformation.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral No problem Daniel, I've just tested again with Scala 2.10 without touching any of my code, and it works pretty well. I guess it is a "bug" with pre-2.10 scala's version as the other question evokes it. Anyway, thanks :)